# How do I save records to the right schema/tenant?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, multi-tenant

I'm working on a multi-tenant application in Django, using django-tenant-schemas. However, when I save users, they don't seem to be properly attached to their tenants. When I query the list of users on a tenant I get a list of all the users in the database. I can see that the records have the right foreign keys but they all appear to have been lumped together in the same schema.

I looked through this [Multi-tenant schema with django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957185/multi-tenant-schema-with-django) and this [User doesn't exists and no redirect to created tenant in django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012639/user-doesnt-exists-and-no-redirect-to-created-tenant-in-django-project), but I can't get mine to work properly

Here's my tenant model(estates/models.py):

```
from django.db import models
from tenant_schemas.models import TenantMixin
from .managers import EstateManager


# Create your models here.
class Estate(TenantMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    auto_create_schema = True

    objects = models.Manager()
    tenancy = EstateManager()
```

Here's my custom user model (authentication/models.py):

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from estates.models import Estate
from .managers import UserManager


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField('phone', max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField('first name', max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField('last name', max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('active', default=True)
    is_owner = models.BooleanField('is owner', default=True)
    is_security = models.BooleanField('is security', default=False)
    is_resident = models.BooleanField('is resident', default=False)
    estate = models.ForeignKey(Estate, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='people', null=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'
        unique_together = ('phone', 'estate',)
```

Here are my serializers and views:

```
class SignupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    estate = EstateSerializer(many=False, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'email', 'password', 'estate')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        estate = validated_data.pop('estate')

        # save estate
        e = Estate.tenancy.create_estate(name=estate['name'], slug=estate['slug'])
        e.save()

        with schema_context(e.schema_name):
            user = User(**validated_data)
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.estate = e
            user.save()

            # create user token for rest authentication
            Token.objects.create(user=user)

        return user

class SignupView(viewsets.generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SignupSerializer
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

And here's my settings file:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

SHARED_APPS = [
    'tenant_schemas',
    'estates',
    'rest_framework',
    'authentication',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'safedelete',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

TENANT_APPS = [
    # The following Django contrib apps must be in TENANT_APPS
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'core',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = SHARED_APPS + [app for app in TENANT_APPS if app not in SHARED_APPS]

TENANT_MODEL = "estates.Estate"
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'tenant_schemas.storage.TenantFileSystemStorage'
```

Comment: Did you end up getting this working? Curious to know how?